AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights: parse not splitting Date and Time from fromMillis() output
I'm trying to split Date and Time from an epoch timestamp (@timestamp) in AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights. Here's my query:
fields @timestamp
| stats fromMillis(@timestamp) as readable_time
| parse readable_time /(?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(?<Time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/
| display Date, Time
| limit 10000 

I also tried this (same result):
fields @timestamp
| stats fromMillis(@timestamp) as readable_time
| parse readable_time /(?<Date>[^T]+)T(?<Time>[^Z]+)/
| display Date, Time
| limit 10

What I Expect
The stats function converts the epoch milliseconds into a readable ISO 8601 timestamp (e.g., 2024-12-11T09:02:06Z) stored in the readable_time field.
The parse statement extracts:
Date as 2024-12-11
Time as 09:02:06
Problem
The readable_time field is populated correctly (e.g., 2024-12-11T09:02:06Z).
However, the Date and Time fields remain empty after parsing.
Environment
Service: AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights
Querying standard CloudWatch logs with the @timestamp field.
Questions
Is there an issue with how parse interacts with the stats-generated readable_time field?
Should parse be used differently for fields generated via stats or fromMillis()?
Are there limitations in how regex works in CloudWatch Logs Insights?
Any help would be appreciated!

@John Rotenstein, I’d greatly appreciate it if you could take a look at my question. I’m new to AWS and might be missing something, but I could really use your expertise. Thanks in advance for any help!
